# javascript replace not working as expected

Tags: javascript, replace

```
    <pre>
    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""


       "

    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.webfaction.com

    250-VRFY

    "


    "

     "

    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6

    "

    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""

    SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "235 2.0.0 Authentication successful

    "
    very long message here


    </pre>{"message":"My message.","status":1}
```

Also in some cases the message to be replaced can be  `</pre>{"message":"My message.","status":1}` .

In both cases it is to be replaced by `{"message":"My message.","status":1}`

I'm doing something like this `msg = msg.replace(/^[<pre>]*[.]*<\/pre>{/m, '{'));`

But it is not working...need some help

Comment: Huh? Can you scrap some of the code above so we are only looking at what we need to see (i.e. do we need to see the SMTP stuff?). Also you want to replace `{"message":"My message.","status":1}` with `{"message":"My message.","status":1}`? I think you need to revise your question, then I will happily help

Comment: I've already striped it enough, just want to make sure that any special character or new line is not causing any trouble. Made the question language clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
msg = msg.replace(/^[\s\S]*<\/pre>({[^}]*})/, '$1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply remove `^` from your regular expression since you don't need it to match from the string beggining.

Comment: Then it might cause trouble in case my message contains any <pre> type string ( I've no control over the message)